# What should I check in my ASP.NET application to make sure it won't run out of resources?

Tags: asp.net, resources

We have a website on IIS7 using ASP.NET Routing that seems as though it might be running out of resources.
It just hangs after a few days, there is no error message or apparent crash.

We are making sure every .Open command is matched by a .Close command on the database connection.
We are doing the same with file Open/Close but there are very few of those.

Is there anything else we should check?

Comment: Instead of jumping straight into code - do you have perfmon running in the background to capture stats? Should tell you I/O wait times, connections, throughput, etc.

Perfmon knows all.

Answer (score 0):

From another user response:

> You want to add a rule to ignore
>   certain routes. See:
>   [Asp.Net Routing: How do I ignore multiple wildcard routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302/asp-net-routing-how-do-i-ignore-multiple-wildcard-routes)
>   or 
>   http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx

Comment: How do I know which routes to ignore?

Answer (score 0):

Try [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

Call me in the morning  (:))